# Storing KineticJS json string in mySQL and then get it with other page to reload the canvas

Tags: php, mysql, json, kineticjs

I hope you will understand what my problem is...

I built a little T-Shirt-Shop with KineticJS.

I store the stage with toJSON() in a json-string and I save that in mySQL database.

Now when I try to get that string with an other page from my database and insert that string into the KineticJS function

```
    var stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container');
```

it doesn't work.

The curious thing is that when I look into my database and I copy the whole string directly into my javascript it does work. Just the fact that I get the string from my database with javascript, save it in a variable and then try to use it gets me an "unexpected token" error.

Comment: When you "get" the JSON variable from your DB and store it into a Javascript variable, just before calling Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'container'); is your var json exactly the same string as in the database? It's hard to help without being able to see more. Try googling "json unexpected token" I found some various results that may help you..

Comment: Could you please tell me how you stored the json string to the sql database?  Im not sure how to do that from javascript.  If you could help me that would be amazing :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the your "json" variable is a string, not an object.

Otherwise, make it a string:

```
JSON.stringify(json);
```